# PHP DomDocument HTML Manipulation

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I have the following HTML.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="current">Current Div</div>
</div>
```

Using DomDocument in PHP, I am trying to add an extra div to the HTML before the div with the id of "current".

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="new">New Div</div>
    <div id="current">Current Div</div>
</div>
```

When I use the following code, it appears to add the div inside the div with the id of "current", but before the content of this div.Can anyone tell me why this is and how I can get the results like the HTML above? (See HTML Issue Below)

**Current PHP**

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->formatOutput = true;

$doc->loadHTMLFile('index.html');

$head = $doc->getElementById('current');
$base = $doc->createElement('div', 'New Div');
$base->setAttribute('id', 'new');
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

**HTML Issue**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="current">
        <div id="new">New Div</div>
        Current Div
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

PHP

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->formatOutput = true;

$doc->loadHTMLFile('index.html');
$container = $doc->getElementById('container');
$current = $doc->getElementById('username');
$new = $doc->createElement('div', 'New Div');

$new->setAttribute('id', 'new');
$container->insertBefore($new, $current);
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Not Found Error' 
in index.php:55 Stack trace: #0 index.php(55): 
DOMNode->insertBefore(Object(DOMElement), Object(DOMElement))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DOMNode::insertBefore()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.insertbefore.php):

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->loadHTMLFile('index.html');

$container = $doc->getElementById('container');
$current = $doc->getElementById('current');
$new = $doc->createElement('div', 'New Div');

$new->setAttribute('id', 'new');
$container->insertBefore($new, $current);

var_dump($doc->saveHTML());
```

This yields:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="new">New Div</div>
            <div id="current">Current Div</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT**

Referring to your reported issue... I see the problem: `input#username` is not an immediate child of `div#container`, it's an immediate child of `form`. So you need to get the `form` element as a `DOMNode` object, not its parent `div#container`. Easiest way to do this is add an id to the `form` and do something like this:

```
$form = $doc->getElementById('form');
$username = $doc->getElementById('username');
$username->setAttribute('value', 'Enter username!');

var_dump($doc->saveHTML());
```

This is based on the the following HTML. Note the `form` element has an id:

```
<div id="container">
    <form id="form" method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    </form>
</div>
```

If for some reason you cannot add an id to the form element, you can traverse from `div#container` like so:

```
// find div#container element
$container = $doc->getElementBy('id');
// find all form elements that are children of div#container
$forms = $container->getElementsByTagName('form');

if (0 !== $forms->length) {
   $form = $forms->item(0);
}

// etc.
```

**EDIT #2**

I almost forgot XPath... If you want to get more succinct/adventurous you can use [`DOMXPath::query()`](https://www.php.net/domxpath.query) to find DOM nodes:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$form  = $xpath->query('body/div[@id="container"]/form')->item(0);
$input = $xpath->query('body//input[@id="username"]')->item(0);
```

The XPath query syntax is pretty cryptic but powerful, I cannot say I'm an expert by any means, so I cannot speak for the efficiency of these queries. Also you might want to add error checking - the `query` method returns a `DOMNodeList` which has a `length` property.

Finally it's worth noting that `DOMDocument` decorates your HTML fragment with a `DOCTYPE` and `html` and `body` tags; this is why the XPath query traverses  from `body`.

Comment: How come the script breaks when referencing an id of a input textbox rather than the div with id "current"? - What's the difference?

Comment: Hi Richy. It breaks? Interesting... Are you getting a specific error? The following works for me: `$input = $doc->createElement('input');
$input->setAttribute('type', 'text');
$input->setAttribute('id', 'foo');
$input->setAttribute('value', 'bar');

$container->insertBefore($input, $current);
`

Comment: I have updated my original post to include further details :)

Comment: you know... I think I misread your comment - does the `input` element already exist in  `index.html`? If so, can you post the line of PHP that is causing the issue.

Comment: No worries..the html does already contain the input element. I have pasted the php, html and error in my original post. It doesn't appear to like the insertBefore method?

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question as answered if it resolved your issue :)